# Command "hg log <dir_name>" works incorrect

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I had to deal with VCS Mercurial.

I have repo with next structure:

```
.
..
.hg
.hgignore
.last_commit.txt
css
img
index.html
```

When i am using command `hg log css/` i get next output:

```
changeset:   5:0f536052d835
tag:         tip
user:        my_name
date:        Mon Jul 24 14:48:39 2023 +0000
summary:     css/main.css changed

changeset:   3:9c045cf0b611
user:        my_name
date:        Mon Jul 24 08:37:00 2023 +0000
summary:     css/main.css changed

changeset:   1:5cea5517c85b
user:        my_name
date:        Mon Jul 24 08:13:37 2023 +0000
summary:     js/main.js changed
```

The question is that: Why the output indicates directory `js`? Exactly this file `js/main.js changed`.

Where the information is stored шт Mercurial repo?

I am wait next result of command `hg log css/`:

```
changeset:   5:0f536052d835
tag:         tip
user:        my_name
date:        Mon Jul 24 14:48:39 2023 +0000
summary:     css/main.css changed

changeset:   3:9c045cf0b611
user:        my_name
date:        Mon Jul 24 08:37:00 2023 +0000
summary:     css/main.css changed
```

Comment: Is there anything in the .hgignore file with `js` in it?  It is possible to ignore a file which is still in the VCS.

Comment: In .hgignore not located files with .js